# Cold, warm game-how can I make the random number not to change every time user put a guess number in JavaScript . There is no limit on guess answer

Tags: javascript, html

I am just starting with JS and I did the game wmr-cold with a random number (between 1-500).
However, it worked perfectly when I set the random number as a "fixed number" just to try.
Now, the random number is made with:

```
numAleatori= Math.ceil((Math.random() * 500)+1)
```

Every time the user is guessing, the random number changes so it makes it impossible to finish the game.

```js
function adivina() {
  "use strict";
  let num, numAleatori, result;
  result = document.getElementById("resultado").value;
  num = Number(document.getElementById("number").value);
  console.log("num", num);

  numAleatori = Math.ceil((Math.random() * 500) + 1);
  console.log("numAleatori", numAleatori);
  if (num == numAleatori) {
    alert("Congrats! You have nailed it. The number is " + numAleatori + " !");
  } else if (numAleatori - num >= 50) {
    alert("Cold, cold. Your number is too small.");
    "<style> backgroundColor = #990000</style>";
  } else if (num - numAleatori >= 50) {
    alert("Cold, cold. Your number is too big.")
  } else if (numAleatori - num >= 15 && numAleatori - num < 50) {
    alert("Warm, warm. Your number is too small.");
  } else if (num - numAleatori >= 15 && num - numAleatori < 50) {
    alert("Warm, warm. Your number is too big.");
  } else if (numAleatori - num < 15 && numAleatori - num > 0) {
    alert("Hot, hot. Your number is too small.");
  } else if (num - numAleatori < 15 && num - numAleatori > 0) {
    alert("Hot, hot. Your number is too big.");
  }

}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(216, 238, 238);
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.enunciado {
  background-color: rgb(214, 132, 132);
}

.ejercicio {
  margin-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="enunciado">

  <p>Realizar un juego para adivinar un número aleatorio N entre 1 y 500.</p>

  Si la distancia entre el número a adivinar y el del usuario es de 50 o más, el programa deberá decir: "Frío, frío: tu número es mayor" o "Frío, frío: tu número es más pequeño"</p>



  <p>Si la distancia entre el número a adivinar y el del usuario está entre 15 y 50, el programa deberá decir:</p>

  <p>“Tebi, Tebi: tu número es mayor” o “Tebi, Tebi: tu número es más pequeño”</p>



  <p>Y si la distancia entre el número a adivinar y el del usuario y si la distancia es menor a 15, el programa deberá decir: “Caliente, caliente: tu número es mayor” o “Caliente, caliente: tu número es más pequeño”</p>



  El proceso termina cuando el usuario acierta.

</div>
<div class="ejercicio">
  <p><strong> Adivina el número:</strong></p>
  <p>Prueba tu suerte<input type="number" id="number"></p>
  <p>Adivina<input type="botton" onClick='adivina()'></p>
  <p id="resultado"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You must not re-assign your variable inside your function. Every time `Math.random()` is called, it will return a new random value. Make sure to only call it once in the beginning:

```html
<script>
"use strict";
// initialize _once_ before function:
let numAleatori= Math.ceil((Math.random() * 500)+1);

function adivina() {
  let result = document.getElementById("resultado").value;
  let num = Number(document.getElementById("number").value);
  console.log("num", num);

  console.log("numAleatori", numAleatori);
  if (num == numAleatori) {
    alert("Congrats! You have nailed it. The number is "+ numAleatori+ " !");
  } else if (numAleatori - num >= 50) {
    alert("Cold, cold. Your number is too small.");
    // "<style> backgroundColor = #990000</style>"; this doesn't do anything
  } else if (num - numAleatori >= 50) {
     alert("Cold, cold. Your number is too big.") 
  } else if (numAleatori - num >= 15 && numAleatori - num < 50) {
     alert("Warm, warm. Your number is too small.");
  } else if (num - numAleatori >= 15 && num - numAleatori < 50) {
     alert("Warm, warm. Your number is too big.");
  } else if (numAleatori - num < 15 && numAleatori - num > 0) {
     alert("Hot, hot. Your number is too small.");
  } else if (num - numAleatori < 15 && num - numAleatori > 0) {
     alert("Hot, hot. Your number is too big.");
  }
        
}
</script>
```

Also note how your conditions contain `numAleatori - num` repeatedly. This is the difference between the number-to-be-guessed and your guess. I suggest extracting it to a variable `difference` before your conditions and then check the difference. This will make your code a lot easier.

Comment: so my whole code is based on the difference between random number and guess number, so how can I do it? Should I create a variable difference?

Comment: @zuzanna that would help simplfying the code, but that's only refactoring and doesn't change any functionality of your code. The question was about the random number changing between calls and the fix for that is contained in my answer.

Comment: Hi, I created two variables for difference(dif1 and dif2-so the program knows if the guess number is biger or smaller) but same happens. The problem I think is that I think I should have used while so the game does not finish until the right answer is given and maybe then the random number wont change..however, not sure how to inser while with for

Comment: @zuzanna You don't need two differences. If the guess was higher, the difference is positive, if the guess was lower, the difference is negative. I don't know what you mean with a loop. The function is called every time the button is clicked and will evaluate the current guess. Have you applied the change from my answer already? But this is different from the original question. If you have another question, please post a new one. Stackoverflow is not a chatforum to "help me debug my code together", it's a Q&A site for specific problems.